# Using Regex groups in bash

Tags: regex, linux, unix, command-line

Greetings,

I've got a directory with a list of pdfs in it:

`file1.pdf, file2.pdf, morestuff.pdf ... etc.`

I want to convert these pdfs to pngs, ie

`file1.png, file2.png, morestuff.png ... etc.`

The basic command is,

`convert from to`,

But I'm having trouble getting convert to rename to the same file name.  The obvious 'I wish it worked this way' is

`convert *.pdf *.png`

But clearly that doesn't work.  My thought process is that I should utilize regular expression grouping here, to say somethink like

`convert (*).pdf %1.png`

but that clearly isn't the right syntax.  I'm wondering **what the correct syntax is**, and whether there's a better approach (that doesn't require jumping into perl or python) that I'm ignoring.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for files in *.pdf 
do  
   if [ -f "$files" ];then
      convert "$files" "${files%.pdf}.png"
   fi
done
```

if you need to do it recursively,

```
find /path -type f -iname "*.pdf" | while read -r FILE
do
   convert "$FILE" "${FILE%.pdf}.png"
done
```

Comment: Internet surfer: If you're looking for a one-line solution, see below.

Answer (score 5):

If you *really* wanted to use regex, Bash≥3.1 supports regular expressions.

```
for f in *.pdf; do
    [[ $f =~ ^(.*)\.pdf$ ]] &&
    convert "$f" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}.png"
done
```

And all systems should have the shell utility [`expr`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/utilities/expr.html).

```
for f in *.pdf; do
    match=$(expr "$f" : '\(.*\)\.pdf$') &&
    convert "$f" "$match.png"
done
```

But Bash's [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) (as demonstrated in the other answers) works better for simple cases like this.

Answer (score 4):

```
for f in *.pdf
do
  convert "$f" "${f%.pdf}.png"
done
```

Comment: That appears to work, thank you!  Can you elaborate on how/why?

Comment: It uses parameter substitution to cut away the extension, then replaces it with its own. http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html

Answer (score 1):

```
ls *.pdf | sed 's/\"/\\"/;s/^\(.*\).pdf$/convert "&" "\1.png"/' | bash
```

Comment: What if the filenames contain backslashes or quotation marks?

Comment: have you tried the command? it works fine with backslash or quotes.

Comment: `touch \".pdf` or heck, to be evil, `touch '$(rm -rf /).pdf'`

Comment: you  won't be able to create `touch '$(rm -rf /).pdf'` because `/` is illegal for file name. As for quotes, its a matter of escaping.

Comment: way to get it to work inline.  File names didn't (in this case) contain any potentially worrysome characters.